# face share link displays subdomain's details

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

Dont know if this have been answered before. 
Whenever sombody clicks the like button on a page on my site, facebook displays the wrong details but directs to the correct page.
It displays the meta info of the subdomain that we use when we direct to the mobile version of the site.
How do I get facebook to display the correct title, description and image in the share link?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page in the debugger at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - this will show you what metadata Facebook is detecting on your page

Comment: I already did. this is the link im posting http://cbn.co.za/dailynews/5776.html. Facebook gives me the details of the mobile site on wap.cbn.co.za

Comment: That's correct, your page is redirecting there, it's a configuration problem on your side:

    curl -i "cbn.co.za/dailynews/5776.html" 
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2011 13:51:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13
Location: http://wap.cbn.co.za/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: thanks @igy.we have set up that subdomain and nowhere in the code is there a redirect from the actual site to the mobile site but it works cause it redirects when it detects mobile browsers. It made my job alot easier cause we never bothered adding a redirect bcause of that.I will give the people we host with a call.

Comment: You could special case the Facebook crawler - once Facebook gets the tags it will look fine on Facebook ( see http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/bot-detail?bot=FacebookExternalHit for the UA strings)